# how to resolve the "Cookie Without SameSite Attribute" on azure app gateway Affinity cookie

Tags: node.js, azure, cookies, azure-application-gateway, azure-load-balancer

Found DAST scan error "Cookie Without SameSite Attribute" on Frond end application

Front end application build on node js and React js, deployed into azure VM and access via azure application gateway.

I can see the three cookies are added back in response object in browser.

Set-Cookie: ApplicationGatewayAffinity=fdasfdfsafdfasa; path=/; domain=xxxxx-xx.xxx.xx.uk
Set-Cookie: ApplicationGatewayAffinityCORS=fdsfdafdsafdfxfdfssafs; path=/; domain=xxxx-xxxx.xxxx.co.uk; secure
Set-Cookie: bm_sv=fdafdfsdfasffasdfsafsdfsafasffsadffdsfsfasfsdfsfxvxgdhgfwefw; Domain=.xxxxx.co.uk; Path=/; Max-Age=7003; HttpOnly

Error clearly showing that it will be clear by adding "Samesite" Attribute in cookie. But i am bit new to azure and not find the azure documentation to add the "Samesite" attribute. Please help on this

Sorry if i am not clearly elaborate the question. Please free to ask if you do not understand question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set the samesite attribute on bm\_sv cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65702476/how-to-set-the-samesite-attribute-on-bm-sv-cookie)

Comment: Still not resolved and waiting for answers.